# normalize-space not working on scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am trying to extract chapter titles and their subtitles from a web page in the url. This is my spider

```
import scrapy
from ..items import ContentsPageSFBItem

class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "contentspage_sfb"
    #allowed_domains = ["web"]
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/shell-programming-in/9780134496696/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
            item = ContentsPageSFBItem()
            item['content_item'] = response.xpath('normalize-space(//ol[@class="detail-toc"]//*/text())').extract();
            length = len(response.xpath('//ol[@class="detail-toc"]//*/text()').extract()); #extract()
            full_url_list = list();
            title_list = list();
            for i in range(1,length+1):
                full_url_list.append(response.url)  
            item["full_url"] = full_url_list
            title = response.xpath('//title[1]/text()').extract();
            for j in range(1,length+1):
                title_list.append(title)  
            item["title"] = title_list
            return item
```

Even though I use the normalise fucntion in my xpath to remove the spaces, I get the following result in my csv

```
content_item,full_url,title
"

      ,Chapter 1,



      ,


  ,

      ,Instructor Introduction,

      ,00:01:00,



  ,

  ,

      ,Course Overview,
```

How do I get the result with at most only one new line after each entry?

Comment: What your expected output should be? Did you want to scrape all text within `Table of Contents` ? The page from your code doesn't have `Instructor Introduction` text and other text from your csv file.

Comment: yes the table of contents

Comment: I suggest you use a [scrapy shell](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html), it's quite a handy tool for testing and debugging you spider code. You can test your xpath selectors and see what they return. For example, your `item["title"]` returns a list of lists that contains identical strings. Can you specify what expected output should be from `item["title"]` and `item["full_url"]`?

Comment: @vold thanks. That is by design actually. My intention is to print the table of contents along with the url and title in a proper csv format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all text within `Table of Contents` section you need to change your xpath expression in `item['content_item']` to:

```
item['content_item'] = response.xpath('//ol[@class="detail-toc"]//a/text()').extract()
```

You can rewrite you spider code like this:

```
import scrapy

class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "contentspage_sfb"
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/shell-programming-in/9780134496696/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = dict()     # change dict to your scrapy item
        for link in response.xpath('//ol[@class="detail-toc"]//a'):
            item['link_text'] = link.xpath('text()').extract_first()
            item['link_url'] = response.urljoin(link.xpath('@href').extract_first())
            yield item

# Output:
{'link_text': 'About This E-Book', 'link_url': 'https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/shell-programming-in/9780134496696/pref00.html#pref00'}
{'link_text': 'Title Page', 'link_url': 'https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/shell-programming-in/9780134496696/title.html#title'}
```

Comment: I still get spaces between the titles.

Comment: It's weird. Did you try to test my xpath expression in scrapy shell? What output from running  `response.xpath('//ol[@class="detail-toc"]//a/text()').extract()` ? [Output](http://icecream.me/24349dd3e159e2847f398c7a1ea0ea3a)

Comment: For each `a` tag in the `Table of content`, you want a text and href value? If so you can make a loop over all `a` tags and extract desired value.

Comment: got it. One final doubt. The csv contains the result as one text. how do i separate the results into rows?